# Retrieving objects from Parse.com in Android

Tags: android, parse-platform

I'm trying to make a ParseQuery to retrieve items from parse.com. At the moment, it always returns null when the app first tries this query, even though I know there are 3 objects there. Can anyone tell me why or help me fix this problem?

```
ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = new ParseQuery<ParseObject>("DreamCloud");
query.orderByDescending("_created_at");

try {
    dreams = query.find();
    } catch (ParseException e) {

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check your objects's ACLs. Are they only readable by a subset of users? Are they globally readable?

Comment: Thanks! I completely forgot to check that!